# Spring Boot between 2.0.9 and 2.1.0 Issue with eclipselink ddl auto generate

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data, eclipselink

Created new project with Spring boot `2.1.0 RELEASE` and my `pom.xml` contains this

```
..
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
    <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
..
```

I am configuring it using `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean` and there is no `application.properties` file :

```
@Bean
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    em.setDataSource(dataSource());
    em.setPackagesToScan("com.xxxx.api.model");
    em.setPersistenceUnitName("xxxx-pu");
    Properties prop = new Properties();
    prop.putAll(getVendorProperties());

    em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
    em.setJpaProperties(prop);
    return em;
}

protected Map<String, String> getVendorProperties() {
    final Map<String, String> ret = new HashMap<>();
    ret.put(PersistenceUnitProperties.BATCH_WRITING, BatchWriting.JDBC);
    ret.put(PersistenceUnitProperties.WEAVING, "false");
    ret.put(PersistenceUnitProperties.LOGGING_LEVEL, "ALL");
    ret.put(PersistenceUnitProperties.DDL_GENERATION, PersistenceUnitProperties.DROP_AND_CREATE);
    return ret;
}
```

I have a very simple class `Account.java`  in `com.xxxx.api.model`

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name="ACCOUNT")
public class Account{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @XmlAttribute
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "ID", nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    private String username;

    private String password;

}
```

By using these configuration and classes I am not able to generate the ddl automatically .

The output log looks like this :

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.1.0.RELEASE)

2019-12-27 01:47:19.447  INFO 31168 --- [           main] com.xxxx.api.ApiApplication          : Starting ApiApplication on server with PID 31168 (/home/user/NetBeansProjects/xxxx-api/target/classes started by user in /home/user/NetBeansProjects/xxxx-api)
2019-12-27 01:47:19.451  INFO 31168 --- [           main] com.xxxx.api.ApiApplication          : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2019-12-27 01:47:20.211  INFO 31168 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2019-12-27 01:47:20.233  INFO 31168 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 15ms. Found 0 repository interfaces.
2019-12-27 01:47:20.962  INFO 31168 --- [           main] com.xxxx.api.config.Environment      : Env: null
2019-12-27 01:47:20.962  INFO 31168 --- [           main] com.xxxx.api.config.Environment      : Level 4: 
2019-12-27 01:47:20.962  INFO 31168 --- [           main] com.xxxx.api.config.Environment      : Property : development
2019-12-27 01:47:20.965  INFO 31168 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'envConfig' of type [com.xxxx.api.config.Environment] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2019-12-27 01:47:21.028  INFO 31168 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'dataSource' of type [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2019-12-27 01:47:21.032  INFO 31168 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'JPAConfig' of type [com.xxxx.api.config.JPAConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$9bc8315d] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2019-12-27 01:47:21.146  INFO 31168 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$7e9c54] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2019-12-27 01:47:21.712  INFO 31168 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2019-12-27 01:47:21.741  INFO 31168 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2019-12-27 01:47:21.741  INFO 31168 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/9.0.12
2019-12-27 01:47:21.751  INFO 31168 --- [           main] o.a.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener   : The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: [/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib]
2019-12-27 01:47:21.860  INFO 31168 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2019-12-27 01:47:21.861  INFO 31168 --- [           main] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2325 ms
2019-12-27 01:47:21.922  INFO 31168 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2019-12-27 01:47:21.923  INFO 31168 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2019-12-27 01:47:21.924  INFO 31168 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'formContentFilter' to: [/*]
2019-12-27 01:47:21.925  INFO 31168 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2019-12-27 01:47:21.925  INFO 31168 --- [           main] .s.DelegatingFilterProxyRegistrationBean : Mapping filter: 'springSecurityFilterChain' to: [/*]
2019-12-27 01:47:21.926  INFO 31168 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Servlet dispatcherServlet mapped to [/]
2019-12-27 01:47:23.821  INFO 31168 --- [           main] liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor      : SELECT COUNT(*) FROM xxxx.DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK
2019-12-27 01:47:23.825  INFO 31168 --- [           main] liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor      : SELECT COUNT(*) FROM xxxx.DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK
2019-12-27 01:47:23.829  INFO 31168 --- [           main] liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor      : SELECT `LOCKED` FROM xxxx.DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK WHERE ID=1
2019-12-27 01:47:23.850  INFO 31168 --- [           main] l.lockservice.StandardLockService        : Successfully acquired change log lock
2019-12-27 01:47:25.618  INFO 31168 --- [           main] liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor      : SELECT MD5SUM FROM xxxx.DATABASECHANGELOG WHERE MD5SUM IS NOT NULL LIMIT 1
2019-12-27 01:47:25.619  INFO 31168 --- [           main] liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor      : SELECT COUNT(*) FROM xxxx.DATABASECHANGELOG
2019-12-27 01:47:25.620  INFO 31168 --- [           main] l.c.StandardChangeLogHistoryService      : Reading from xxxx.DATABASECHANGELOG
2019-12-27 01:47:25.621  INFO 31168 --- [           main] liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor      : SELECT * FROM xxxx.DATABASECHANGELOG ORDER BY DATEEXECUTED ASC, ORDEREXECUTED ASC
2019-12-27 01:47:25.627  INFO 31168 --- [           main] l.lockservice.StandardLockService        : Successfully released change log lock
[EL Fine]: server: 2019-12-27 01:47:25.981--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--Configured server platform: org.eclipse.persistence.platform.server.NoServerPlatform
[EL Finest]: jpa: 2019-12-27 01:47:25.993--ServerSession(1340776217)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--Begin predeploying Persistence Unit xxxx-pu; session /file:/home/user/NetBeansProjects/xxxx-api/target/classes/_xxxx-pu; state Initial; factoryCount 0
[EL Finest]: properties: 2019-12-27 01:47:25.994--ServerSession(1340776217)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--property=eclipselink.orm.throw.exceptions; default value=true
[EL Finest]: properties: 2019-12-27 01:47:25.995--ServerSession(1340776217)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--property=eclipselink.multitenant.tenants-share-emf; value=false
[EL Finest]: properties: 2019-12-27 01:47:25.995--ServerSession(1340776217)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--property=eclipselink.multitenant.tenants-share-cache; default value=false
[EL Finer]: metadata: 2019-12-27 01:47:26.01--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--Searching for mapping file: [META-INF/orm.xml] at root URL: [file:/home/user/NetBeansProjects/xxxx-api/target/classes/].
[EL Finer]: metadata: 2019-12-27 01:47:26.014--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--Searching for mapping file: [META-INF/eclipselink-orm.xml] at root URL: [file:/home/user/NetBeansProjects/xxxx-api/target/classes/].
[EL Config]: metadata: 2019-12-27 01:47:26.114--ServerSession(1340776217)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--The access type for the persistent class [class com.xxxx.api.model.Account] is set to [FIELD].
[EL Config]: metadata: 2019-12-27 01:47:26.136--ServerSession(1340776217)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--The alias name for the entity class [class com.xxxx.api.model.Account] is being defaulted to: Account.
[EL Config]: metadata: 2019-12-27 01:47:26.154--ServerSession(1340776217)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--The column name for element [password] is being defaulted to: PASSWORD.
[EL Config]: metadata: 2019-12-27 01:47:26.156--ServerSession(1340776217)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--The column name for element [username] is being defaulted to: USERNAME.
[EL Finest]: jpa: 2019-12-27 01:47:26.168--ServerSession(1340776217)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--End predeploying Persistence Unit xxxx-pu; session /file:/home/user/NetBeansProjects/xxxx-api/target/classes/_xxxx-pu; state Predeployed; factoryCount 1
[EL Finer]: metamodel: 2019-12-27 01:47:26.176--ServerSession(1340776217)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--Canonical Metamodel class [com.xxxx.api.model.Account_] not found during initialization.
[EL Finer]: metamodel: 2019-12-27 01:47:26.177--ServerSession(1340776217)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--Canonical Metamodel class [com.xxxx.api.model.BaseModel_] not found during initialization.
2019-12-27 01:47:26.177  INFO 31168 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'xxxx-pu'
2019-12-27 01:47:26.533  INFO 31168 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2019-12-27 01:47:27.020  INFO 31168 --- [           main] .s.s.UserDetailsServiceAutoConfiguration : 

Using generated security password: eaf18e76-a0bc-4afd-853a-2ee7138da3dc

2019-12-27 01:47:27.212  INFO 31168 --- [           main] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Creating filter chain: any request, [org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@7ec5d3e1, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@694dc99b, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@518ed9b4, org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter@31c800a5, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@590ab84, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter@1f7853af, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter@342a5b57, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLogoutPageGeneratingFilter@3b235623, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter@153cf928, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@6d71f296, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@51a73873, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@3ddc5a75, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@20e73e41, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@4a49ce3a, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@17d25e1d]
2019-12-27 01:47:27.428  INFO 31168 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2019-12-27 01:47:27.433  INFO 31168 --- [           main] com.xxxx.api.ApiApplication          : Started ApiApplication in 8.813 seconds (JVM running for 9.538)
```

If I changed my pom.xml's `spring.boot.version` to `2.0.9.RELEASE`  it works without any issue and generates the `ACCOUNT` table as well.

Comment: please add springboot startup logs and application.properties file

Comment: @Sarjit I have updated it and i do not have anything in application.properties

Comment: create-drop: Creates the database and drops it when SessionFactory closes. please check db instance exists for not and also try create instead of create-drop

Comment: I tried it already but still the same. and it is not create-drops i am using drop and create  which means it will clear tables first before creating one.

Comment: in documentation, it was clearly written if any issue persist then it will not work. https://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.5/jpa/extensions/p_ddl_generation.htm

Comment: @Sarjit There is only one Entity class in there and I am amazed why isn't it working. However, if I changed my spring.boot.version to 2.0.9.RELEASE it works correctly. Also when doing with 2.0.9.RELEASE the properties that I set are shown in the console log as well.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204938/discussion-between-privatejava-and-sarjit).

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue. From Spring Boot `2.1.0.RELEASE` the Eclipselink's Deployment of Persistence Unit will happen only after we hit any REST Controller endpoints. So I changed the code to initialize it after the application is ready. It is kind of hacky way but works .

```
public class JPAConfig implements ApplicationContextAware { 

// ...

    private ApplicationContext context;

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
        this.context = applicationContext;
    }

    @EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class)
    public void startup() {
        EntityManager bean = this.context.getBean(EntityManager.class);
        try {
            bean.clear();
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
//...
}
```

After running this I get the logs like this :

```
EL Finest]: jpa: 2019-12-27 17:49:05.083--ServerSession(1197389053)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--Begin deploying Persistence Unit xxxx-pu; session /file:/home/user/NetBeansProjects/xxxx-api/target/classes/_xxxx-pu; state Predeployed; factoryCount 1
[EL Finer]: server: 2019-12-27 17:49:05.11--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--Detected server platform: org.eclipse.persistence.platform.server.NoServerPlatform.
[EL Finer]: 2019-12-27 17:49:05.111--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--initializing session manager
[EL Finer]: server: 2019-12-27 17:49:05.112--ServerSession(1197389053)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--Detected server platform: org.eclipse.persistence.platform.server.NoServerPlatform.
[EL Finest]: properties: 2019-12-27 17:49:05.113--ServerSession(1197389053)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--property=eclipselink.logging.level; value=ALL
[EL Finest]: properties: 2019-12-27 17:49:05.113--ServerSession(1197389053)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--property=eclipselink.logging.level; value=ALL
[EL Finest]: properties: 2019-12-27 17:49:05.116--ServerSession(1197389053)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--property=eclipselink.cache.query-results; value=false
[EL Finest]: properties: 2019-12-27 17:49:05.117--ServerSession(1197389053)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--property=eclipselink.cache.shared.default; value=false
[EL Finest]: properties: 2019-12-27 17:49:05.117--ServerSession(1197389053)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--property=eclipselink.jdbc.batch-writing; value=JDBC
[EL Finest]: properties: 2019-12-27 17:49:05.118--ServerSession(1197389053)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--property=eclipselink.session.customizer; value=com.xxxx.api.config.CamelCaseSessionCustomizer
[EL Info]: 2019-12-27 17:49:05.12--ServerSession(1197389053)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--EclipseLink, version: Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.3.v20160428-59c81c5
[EL Finest]: connection: 2019-12-27 17:49:05.164--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--Database platform: org.eclipse.persistence.platform.database.oracle.Oracle12Platform, regular expression: (?is)oracle.*12.*
[EL Finest]: connection: 2019-12-27 17:49:05.164--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--Database platform: org.eclipse.persistence.platform.database.oracle.Oracle11Platform, regular expression: (?is)oracle.*11.*
[EL Finest]: connection: 2019-12-27 17:49:05.164--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--Database platform: org.eclipse.persistence.platform.database.oracle.Oracle10Platform, regular expression: (?is)oracle.*10.*
[EL Finest]: connection: 2019-12-27 17:49:05.165--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--Database platform: org.eclipse.persistence.platform.database.oracle.Oracle9Platform, regular expression: (?is)oracle.*9.*
[EL Finest]: connection: 2019-12-27 17:49:05.165--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--Database platform: org.eclipse.persistence.platform.database.oracle.OraclePlatform, regular expression: (?is)oracle.*
[EL Finest]: connection: 2019-12-27 17:49:05.165--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--Database platform: org.eclipse.persistence.platform.database.SQLAnywherePlatform, regular expression: SQL\ Anywhere.*
[EL Finest]: connection: 2019-12-27 17:49:05.165--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--Database platform: org.eclipse.persistence.platform.database.SybasePlatform, regular expression: (?i)(sybase.*)|(adaptive\ server\ enterprise.*)|(SQL\ Server.*)
[EL Finest]: connection: 2019-12-27 17:49:05.165--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--Database platform: org.eclipse.persistence.platform.database.SQLServerPlatform, regular expression: (?i)microsoft.*
[EL Finest]: connection: 2019-12-27 17:49:05.165--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--Database platform: org.eclipse.persistence.platform.database.JavaDBPlatform, regular expression: (?i).*derby.*
[EL Finest]: connection: 2019-12-27 17:49:05.166--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--Database platform: org.eclipse.persistence.platform.database.DB2ZPlatform, regular expression: (?i).*db2.*dsn.*
[EL Finest]: connection: 2019-12-27 17:49:05.166--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--Database platform: org.eclipse.persistence.platform.database.DB2MainframePlatform, regular expression: (?i).*db2.*qsq.*
[EL Finest]: connection: 2019-12-27 17:49:05.166--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--Database platform: org.eclipse.persistence.platform.database.DB2Platform, regular expression: (?i).*db2.*
[EL Finest]: connection: 2019-12-27 17:49:05.166--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--Database platform: org.eclipse.persistence.platform.database.PointBasePlatform, regular expression: (?is)pointbase.*
[EL Finest]: connection: 2019-12-27 17:49:05.166--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--Database platform: org.eclipse.persistence.platform.database.MySQLPlatform, regular expression: (?i)mysql.*
[EL Fine]: connection: 2019-12-27 17:49:05.167--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--Detected database platform: org.eclipse.persistence.platform.database.MySQLPlatform
[EL Config]: connection: 2019-12-27 17:49:05.222--ServerSession(1197389053)--Connection(595285180)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--connecting(DatabaseLogin(
    platform=>MySQLPlatform
    user name=> ""
    connector=>JNDIConnector datasource name=>null
))
[EL Config]: connection: 2019-12-27 17:49:05.247--ServerSession(1197389053)--Connection(156850393)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--Connected: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/xxxx?nullNamePatternMatchesAll=true&useUnicode=true&character_set_server=utf8mb4&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&useTimezone=true&serverTimezone=GMT
    User: root@localhost
    Database: MySQL  Version: 5.7.28-0ubuntu0.18.04.4
    Driver: MySQL Connector/J  Version: mysql-connector-java-8.0.17 (Revision: 16a712ddb3f826a1933ab42b0039f7fb9eebc6ec)
[EL Finest]: connection: 2019-12-27 17:49:05.248--ServerSession(1197389053)--Connection(1895707642)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--Connection acquired from connection pool [read].
[EL Finest]: connection: 2019-12-27 17:49:05.249--ServerSession(1197389053)--Connection(1895707642)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--Connection released to connection pool [read].
[EL Config]: connection: 2019-12-27 17:49:05.249--ServerSession(1197389053)--Connection(1039835620)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--connecting(DatabaseLogin(
    platform=>MySQLPlatform
    user name=> ""
    connector=>JNDIConnector datasource name=>null
))
[EL Config]: connection: 2019-12-27 17:49:05.27--ServerSession(1197389053)--Connection(1160393458)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--Connected: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/xxxx?nullNamePatternMatchesAll=true&useUnicode=true&character_set_server=utf8mb4&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&useTimezone=true&serverTimezone=GMT
    User: root@localhost
    Database: MySQL  Version: 5.7.28-0ubuntu0.18.04.4
    Driver: MySQL Connector/J  Version: mysql-connector-java-8.0.17 (Revision: 16a712ddb3f826a1933ab42b0039f7fb9eebc6ec)
[EL Finest]: sequencing: 2019-12-27 17:49:05.292--ServerSession(1197389053)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--sequencing connected, state is Preallocation_Transaction_NoAccessor_State
[EL Finest]: sequencing: 2019-12-27 17:49:05.292--ServerSession(1197389053)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--sequence SEQUENCE: preallocation size 50
[EL Finest]: sequencing: 2019-12-27 17:49:05.293--ServerSession(1197389053)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--sequence SEQ_GEN: preallocation size 50
[EL Info]: connection: 2019-12-27 17:49:05.32--ServerSession(1197389053)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--/file:/home/user/NetBeansProjects/xxxx-api/target/classes/_xxxx-pu login successful
[EL Finest]: query: 2019-12-27 17:49:05.385--ServerSession(1197389053)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--Execute query DataModifyQuery(sql="CREATE TABLE ACCOUNT (ID BIGINT NOT NULL, PASSWD VARCHAR(255), USR VARCHAR(255), PRIMARY KEY (ID))")
[EL Finest]: connection: 2019-12-27 17:49:05.385--ServerSession(1197389053)--Connection(6267871)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--Connection acquired from connection pool [read].
[EL Finest]: connection: 2019-12-27 17:49:05.385--ServerSession(1197389053)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--reconnecting to external connection pool
[EL Fine]: sql: 2019-12-27 17:49:05.402--ServerSession(1197389053)--Connection(991572261)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--CREATE TABLE ACCOUNT (ID BIGINT NOT NULL, PASSWD VARCHAR(255), USR VARCHAR(255), PRIMARY KEY (ID))
[EL Finest]: connection: 2019-12-27 17:49:05.891--ServerSession(1197389053)--Connection(6267871)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--Connection released to connection pool [read].
[EL Finest]: ddl: 2019-12-27 17:49:05.891--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--The table (ACCOUNT) is created.
[EL Finest]: query: 2019-12-27 17:49:05.91--ServerSession(1197389053)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--Execute query DataReadQuery(sql="SELECT * FROM SEQUENCE WHERE SEQ_NAME = 'SEQ_GEN'")
[EL Finest]: connection: 2019-12-27 17:49:05.911--ServerSession(1197389053)--Connection(966446307)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--Connection acquired from connection pool [read].
[EL Finest]: connection: 2019-12-27 17:49:05.911--ServerSession(1197389053)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--reconnecting to external connection pool
[EL Fine]: sql: 2019-12-27 17:49:05.925--ServerSession(1197389053)--Connection(34004511)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--SELECT * FROM SEQUENCE WHERE SEQ_NAME = 'SEQ_GEN'
[EL Finest]: connection: 2019-12-27 17:49:05.928--ServerSession(1197389053)--Connection(966446307)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--Connection released to connection pool [read].
[EL Finer]: metamodel: 2019-12-27 17:49:05.929--ServerSession(1197389053)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--Canonical Metamodel class [com.xxxx.api.model.Account_] not found during initialization.
[EL Finer]: metamodel: 2019-12-27 17:49:05.93--ServerSession(1197389053)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--Canonical Metamodel class [com.xxxx.api.model.BaseModel_] not found during initialization.
[EL Finest]: jpa: 2019-12-27 17:49:05.93--ServerSession(1197389053)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--End deploying Persistence Unit xxxx-pu; session /file:/home/user/NetBeansProjects/xxxx-api/target/classes/_xxxx-pu; state Deployed; factoryCount 1
```

I have tried this on `2.1.0.RELEASE` and latest `2.2.2.RELEASE` as well which works great.